# Parser.parse changes to wrong time zone

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-dateutil

I am using `from dateutil import parser` to parse an input but for some reason it is giving me back the wrong timezone.

My code:
`parser.parse(input_date)`

Input: `Tue May 01 2018 13:23:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

Output: `2018-05-01 13:23:00-02:00`

Does anybody know why the parse method changes the `+2` timezone to `-2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the issue is open on github as Paul said I had to make a custom solution. I parsed the input using `re` and changed it from:
`Tue May 01 2018 13:23:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)` to `Tue May 01 2018 13:23:00 +0200`, `dateutil.parser.parse` had no problem parsing this format.

Answer (score 1):

That is being interpreted as a POSIX style offset, which is specified in a way that is inverted from what you expect. See [the documentation on tzstr](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzstr).

You can see that dealing with this is open [issue #70](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/70) on the tracker.

For now, your best options depend on what your data looks like. If you are generating the strings yourself, changing them to a different format is the easiest choice. If you are parsing arbitrary strings, writing a custom `tzinfos` function or manually detecting this situation and correcting it after the fact may be your best option.